# stop ffmpeg stream at specific time of the day

Tags: ffmpeg

This stream will stop after `3600` seconds with the `-t` option.

Is it possible to stop the stream at a certain **time of the day**, e.g. at 1:00 A.M. using `ffmpeg` only?

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Virtual-Camera" -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k \
-f mpegts -t 3600 udp://10.1.0.102:1234
```

The Docs are very clear about the syntax for [Time duration](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Time-duration).

So something like `-t (1+1)` doesn't work. It is not evaluated to `-t 2`.

I think [Expression Evaluation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation) doesn't help either because it seems to be only valid in filters.

A simple bash solution to stop at `01:00 AM` would be:

```
# Set time to stop
# maximum value is 23:59:59
# use `offset_tomorrow` to set a time tomorrow
time_to_stop="23:59:59"

# remaining seconds until 1 AM
offset_tomorrow=3601

# calculate time difference between maximum time and now and add offset in seconds.
# add 1 hour and 1 minute to get the remaining seconds until 1 AM.
seconds_to_stop=$((`date -d$time_to_stop '+%s'`-`date '+%s'` + $offset_tomorrow))

ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="Virtual-Camera" -preset ultrafast -vcodec libx264 -tune zerolatency -b 900k \
-f mpegts -t $seconds_to_stop udp://10.1.0.102:1234
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general Bash solution would be

```
#!/bin/bash
time_to_stop="$1"  # e.g. 15:47
s=$(date -d"$time_to_stop" '+%s')
now=$(date '+%s')
((s < now)) && ((s+=86400)) # add 24h (in seconds)
t=$((s - now))
```

then use value of `t` as and argument for `-t` (or `-to` ?) in the `ffmpeg` command line.